# Call a certain method before each webservice call

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

Here's the situation. I have a webservice (C# 2.0), which consists of (mainly) a class inheriting from System.Web.Services.WebService. It contains a few methods, which all need to call a method that checks if they're authorized or not.

Basically something like this (pardon the architecture, this is purely as an example):

```
public class ProductService : WebService
{
    public AuthHeader AuthenticationHeader;

    [WebMethod(Description="Returns true")]
    [SoapHeader("AuthenticationHeader")]        
    public bool MethodWhichReturnsTrue()
    {
        if(Validate(AuthenticationHeader))
        {
            throw new SecurityException("Access Denied");
        }
        return true;
    }

    [WebMethod(Description="Returns false")]
    [SoapHeader("AuthenticationHeader")]        
    public bool MethodWhichReturnsFalse()
    {
        if(Validate(AuthenticationHeader))
        {
            throw new SecurityException("Access Denied");
        }
        return false;
    }

    private bool Validate(AuthHeader authHeader)
    {
        return authHeader.Username == "gooduser" && authHeader.Password == "goodpassword";
    }
}
```

As you can see, the method `Validate` has to be called in each method. I'm looking for a way to be able to call that method, while still being able to access the soap headers in a sane way. I've looked at the events in the `global.asax`, but I don't think I can access the headers in that class... Can I?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is what you need to do to get this to work correctly.

It is possible to create your own custom SoapHeader:

```
public class ServiceAuthHeader : SoapHeader
{
    public string SiteKey;
    public string Password;

    public ServiceAuthHeader() {}
}
```

Then you need a SoapExtensionAttribute:

```
public class AuthenticationSoapExtensionAttribute : SoapExtensionAttribute
{
    private int priority;

    public AuthenticationSoapExtensionAttribute()
    {
    }

    public override Type ExtensionType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(AuthenticationSoapExtension);
        }
    }

    public override int Priority
    {
        get
        {
            return priority;
        }
        set
        {
            priority = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And a custom SoapExtension:

```
public class AuthenticationSoapExtension : SoapExtension
{
    private ServiceAuthHeader authHeader;

    public AuthenticationSoapExtension()
    {
    }

    public override object GetInitializer(Type serviceType)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override object GetInitializer(LogicalMethodInfo methodInfo, SoapExtensionAttribute attribute)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override void Initialize(object initializer)
    {        
    }

    public override void ProcessMessage(SoapMessage message)
    {
        if (message.Stage == SoapMessageStage.AfterDeserialize)
        {
            foreach (SoapHeader header in message.Headers)
            {
                if (header is ServiceAuthHeader)
                {
                    authHeader = (ServiceAuthHeader)header;

                    if(authHeader.Password == TheCorrectUserPassword)
                    {
                        return;  //confirmed
                    }
                }
            }

            throw new SoapException("Unauthorized", SoapException.ClientFaultCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your web service add the following header to your method:

```
public ServiceAuthHeader AuthenticationSoapHeader;

[WebMethod]
[SoapHeader("AuthenticationSoapHeader")]
[AuthenticationSoapExtension]
public string GetSomeStuffFromTheCloud(string IdOfWhatYouWant)
{
  return WhatYouWant;
}
```

When you consume this service, you must instantiate the custom header with the correct values and attach it to the request:

```
private ServiceAuthHeader header;
private PublicService ps;

header = new ServiceAuthHeader();
header.SiteKey = "Thekey";
header.Password = "Thepassword";
ps.ServiceAuthHeaderValue = header;

string WhatYouWant = ps.GetSomeStuffFromTheCloud(SomeId);
```

Comment: Not as straightforward as I assumed it to be. Going to try this now.

Comment: It works! Keep in mind that the Visual Studio webbased access doesn't fire the extension, as it doesn't use SOAP to make the request. Got me scratching my head for a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement the so-called SOAP extension by deriving from [SoapExtension base](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension.aspx) class. That way you will be able to inspect an incoming SOAP message and perform validate logic before a particular web method is called.

Answer (score 2):

I'd take a look at adding a security aspect to the methods you're looking to secure. Take a look at [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org), and in particular the OnMethodBoundryAspect type, and OnEntry method.